# Stop first audio when user taps to play a different audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm making an audio app with jQuery mobile which is compiled with phonegap build. The audio plays correctly as it should, but the problem is when an audio is playing and you tap on a new audio to play. The first audio doesn't stop but still continues to play with the second one too. I want to know how I could find a way to stop the first audio playing when a user taps on the second audio file.

```
// JavaScript Document



        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //


       function play2face() {
        playAudio(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/music/audio1.mp3");
        }

        function playras() {
        playAudio(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/music/audio2.mp3");
        }

        function playbecca() {
        playAudio(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/music/audio3.mp3");
        }




        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // Pause audio
        // 
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                this.my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        // 
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                this.my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback 
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        // 
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }

 HTML
```

Play Music | Pause Music | Stop Music

Play Music | Pause Music | Stop Music

Play Music | Pause Music | Stop Music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a call to `stopAudio()` at the top of the `playAudio(src)` funtion?

Like so:

```
function playAudio(src) {
    stopAudio();
    //rest of your function
}
```

Comment: how? can you please phrase it in my script?

Comment: @i_user See edited post.  You already have a reference to the active audio object which stopAduio() already uses to stop the audio.  So all you have to do is *call it.*